# Scroll To Top on Button Click in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I'm new to Flutter, I'm facing this issue,
There is a button below in ScrollController, And when I click it. It should scroll To top.

ScrollController is embedded in SingleChildScrollView

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController)
  );
}
```

I tried using

```
setState(() {
  scrollController.animateTo(0.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.ease);
}
```

Below is the Whole Code

```
Future<void> nextPressed() async {
final bool connectivity = await ConnectivityManager().isInternetAvailable();
if(connectivity) {
  final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
  if (form.validate()) {
    form.save();
    updateDOBError(_dobController.text);
    setState(() {
      if(dobErrorString.isEmpty){
        _errorAlertVisibilityDOB = false;
      }else{
        _errorAlertVisibilityDOB = true;
      }
     
      _errorAlertVisibility = true;
    });

  } else {
    updateDOBError(_dobController.text);
    setState(() {
      if(dobErrorString.isEmpty){
        _errorAlertVisibilityDOB = false;
      }else{
        _errorAlertVisibilityDOB = true;
      }
      errorType = RegistrationErrorType.validationError;
      _errorAlertVisibility = true;
    });
  -->  scrollController.animateTo(0.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
  }
}else{
        const SnackBar snackBar =
  SnackBar(content: Text(AppStrings.no_internet));
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}}
```

The --> is the place, I'm facing issue

[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIkK2.png)

[Issue to be Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4fTn.png)

Comment: Could you explain what is actually happening? Also are there any errors that show in the console?

Comment: Actually I need to scroll to Top, when onClick is pressed

Comment: I think you misunderstood my questions. What behaviour are you currently getting? Is nothing at all happening? Again, are there any errors that show in your console? Your image doesn't provide enough information

Comment: no errors, and nothing happening

Answer (score 8):

Use following on button clicked

```
setState((){
_scrollController.animateTo(
    _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
 );})
```